# Can a constant function be called a function in $x$?

Tags: functions, definition

Suppose I have $y=c$, where $c$ is a constant. We can graph it on the coordinate axes too. Now, which statement is correct to say,

1. $y$ is a constant function of $x$.
2. $y$ is not a function of $x$.

I think that the first statement is correct as if 2nd were correct then vertical line test would have failed. But, I want to confirm if I am thinking correctly or not.

Comment: Yes, a constant function is still a function.

Comment: It might be that you use a different definition for the concept of a function. But for me a function $f:X \rightarrow Y$ is something that assigns one element from the set $Y$ to each element of the set $X$. It makes no difference if all elements from $X$ get assigned the same value (in your case „$c$“).

Comment: You’re confusing vertical and horizontal!

Comment: Both are poor descriptions, and this is yet another case of leaving assumptions unstated, and fussing about when this leads to some confusion. And if you're going for statement #1, how would you respond to my claim that "No, $y$ isn't a constant function of $x$, it is a constant function of $t$."?

Comment: If, in fact, $y$ and $x$ are variables you are interested in, and $y$ is always equal to some constant, then I'd say "$y$ does not depend on $x$" would be a great description. Deciding whether or not you want to consider $y$ as a function of $x$ is a choice that is entirely up to you, and it is equally valid to do so or not to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Calling $f(x)=c$ a “constant function of $x$” is not only unuseful, it is also ambiguous:

$y=c$ and $y=c+0x$ both pass through $(0,c),$

whereas $y=cx^0$ has a hole at $0.$